# Using Plugin.MediaManager to consume stream server from xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to consume an audio stream server with Xamarin Plugin.MediaManager and only works if the url contains mp3 extension like http://urlserver/audio.mp3. If the server url looks like http://urlserver/audio the application fails

Comment: What's your question? If you want to know why this happened, I suggest you read the source code from https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager

Comment: I read that source code, even I use the xamarin.ios example, but only works when my audio stream serve contains .mp3 extension in the url. It's something wrong or cannot use an url withouth .mp3 extension